# Two SQL updates that use CASE statements and need to access previous rows to update the current one

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a dashboard with python and dash/plotly that receives inputs from the user and then run a query on Google BigQuery.

One of the queries updates a column (POR_FT), uses other column (POR_CORR or POR_CLEAN depending of the case statement), a string input from the dashboard (cpi) and previous rows of the updated POR_FT (if rownumber != 1). The table is already created with all columns, so if I run the queries it would update the values from the table.

The query that I was trying to use for this case is:

```
    DECLARE cpi STRING DEFAULT "C";
    UPDATE `xx.yy.zz` t
    SET
    POR_FT = s.POR_FT
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        RN,
        CASE
        WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN POR_CORR
        WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY" THEN POR_CLEAN
        WHEN RN = 1 THEN 0
        WHEN RN > 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN (POR_CORR/5) + (LAG(POR_FT, 1, 0)  OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        WHEN RN > 1 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY" THEN (POR_CLEAN/5) + (LAG(POR_FT, 1, 0)  OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        ELSE (LAG(POR_FT, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        END
        AS POR_FT
    FROM
        `xx.yy.zz`
    WHERE
        DEPTH_M IS NOT NULL
    )
    s
    WHERE
    t.RN = s.RN
```

But does not work correctly, it doesn't update the column. On another question that I made, I got the response that LAG is not intended to be used this way and it would probably need a recursive approach.

The basic calculation when the user inputs "C" on cpi is: if rownumber is 1 and PAY_CLEAN = "PAY", then it simply gets the value of the column POR_CORR. If rn > 1 and PAY_CLEAN = "PAY", then it will get the value from POR_CLEAN divided by 5 plus the value of POR_FT from the previous row. Else, it will simply return the value of POR_FT from the previous row.

Here is a [SAMPLE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AuVv-bcMzYWjArWJXqpYh-3Ogf6iTOzJ/view) of my dataset.

The expected output should look like:

[image: EXPECTED OUTPUT]

The other query looks very similar:

```
    DECLARE cpi STRING DEFAULT "C";
    UPDATE `xx.yy.zz` t
    SET
    t.HPV_CUM = s.HPV_CUM
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        DEPTH_M,
        RN,
        CASE
        WHEN RN < 5 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN HPV_LAMINATED
        WHEN RN < 5 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY" THEN HPV_CLEAN
        WHEN RN < 5 THEN 0
        WHEN RN > 4 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY" THEN (HPV_LAMINATED/5) + (LAG(HPV_CUM, 1)  OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        WHEN RN > 4 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY" THEN (HPV_CLEAN/5) + (LAG(HPV_CUM, 2)  OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        ELSE (LAG(HPV_CUM, 1) OVER(ORDER BY RN))
        END
        AS HPV_CUM
    FROM
        `xx.yy.zz`
    WHERE
        DEPTH_M IS NOT NULL
    )
    s
    WHERE
    t.RN = s.RN
```

So, if I can solve one, I can probably use the same thing on the second one.

How can I make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this looks familiar ;) , explain what's not working in your query. plus a clear explanation of your logic ( based on sample data)

Comment: @eshirvana yeah, it does haha. Your previous one worked perfectly for the case, since it was just to add 0.2 an so on. Those 2 in this question actually don't even generate any values on the update. The expected output in my question is actually what does have in my Sample, except that in my sample doesn't have any value on POR_FT. I will edit my question to have a better explanation of the calculation.

Comment: @eshirvana I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you can do it , the same method:

```
SELECT RN
    , SUM(CASE WHEN (cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY") then (POR_CORR/5) 
               when (cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY") THEN (POR_CLEAN/5) END) OVER (ORDER BY RN) 
    + SUM(CASE WHEN RN = 1 AND cpi = "S" AND PAY_SHALE_COR = "PAY"  then (POR_CORR * 4 /5)
            when RN = 1 AND cpi = "C" AND PAY_CLEAN = "PAY"  THEN POR_CLEAN* 4 /5) ELSE 0 end) OVER () NEW_Pay_FT
FROM `xx.yy.zz`
WHERE DEPTH_M IS NOT NULL
```